# Multiple values in Multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, explode

I want to separate the multiple values in more than one column. for the individual column, I tried the code below

`Team_Parsed = Team.assign(Drivers = Team.Drivers.str.split(",")).explode("Drivers")`
and it worked.

For multiple columns, I have been able to put them in a list using the split method with the following code.

`a = Team.assign(No = Team.No.str.split(","))`

`b = a.assign(Drivers = a.Drivers.str.split(","))`

`d = b.assign(Rounds = b.Rounds.str.split(","))`

I tried

`explode(d, d[["No", "Drivers", 'Rounds']])`
Just to be sure, I tried
`explode(d, ["No", "Drivers", 'Rounds'])` too.

**NameError: name 'explode' is not defined**

Comment: Don't post images of data please.  You can copy/paste the actual data as a table and it would be easier to help.

Comment: Please provide an example for this. I didn't quite get what you're trying to accomplish, but have you tried pd.str.split(pat=",", expand=True) ?     https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: It is not private data that's why I posted the Image.

Answer (score 0):

[Attached Image][1]

I omitted the image while uploading, please find attached the image of the problem statement.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zka8d.png